# How to Load files from BeanShell?

Tags: java, file, scripting, beanshell, system-administration

How do I [iterate the directory contents and put each file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10269862/262852) into a `List` or other collection?

```
thufir@dur:~/beanshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/beanshell$ bsh list_ebooks.bsh 
ebook files to iterate
rw_ Dec 19   368225 1 - foundation - isaac asimov.epub
rw_ Dec 19   395042 2 - foundation and empire - isaac asimov.epub
rw_ Dec 19   374631 3 - second foundation -  isaac asimov.epub
rw_ Dec 19  2084565 4 - foundation's edge -  isaac asimov.epub
rw_ Dec 19  2125777 5 - foundation and earth -  isaac asimov.epub
rw_ Dec 19  2187662 6 - prelude to foundation -  isaac asimov.epub
rw_ Dec 19  2173565 7 - forward to foundation -  isaac asimov.epub
thufir@dur:~/beanshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/beanshell$ cat list_ebooks.bsh 


print("ebook files to iterate");

dir("/home/thufir/ebooks/foundation/");


thufir@dur:~/beanshell$
```

To [bulk convert](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/8057/9853) the format (although `BeanShell` might be overkill).

`BeanShell` will `Load` the file?  The [fine manual](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html#Hello_World):

> Working with Dirctories and Paths BeanShell supports the notion of a
>   current working directory for commands that work with files. The cd()
>   command can be used to change the working directory and pwd() can be
>   used to display the current value. The BeanShell current working
>   directory is stored in the variable bsh.cwd.
>
> All commands that work with files respect the working directory,
>   including the following:
>
> ```
> dir()
> source()
> run(),
> cat()
> load()
> save()
> mv()
> rm()
> addClassPath()
> ```
>
> pathToFile() As a convenience for writing your own scripts and
>   commands you can use the pathToFile() command to translate a relative
>   file path to an absolute one relative to the current working
>   directory. Absolute paths are unmodified.

```
absfilename = pathToFile( filename );
```

[Import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187490/262852) apache file utils?

It cannot be done with [streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53849218/262852).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have to avoid Streams you can go back to old  [`java.io.File.listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) method:

```
List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
File dir = new File("/tmp");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            result.add(f);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```